# Why can I return a string from RIA Services, but not IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I am trying to create a method in my DomainService to return a list of strings. The reason why I am doing this is because I don't want to return whole entities of information. I can create a method to return a single string, as follows:

```
    public string GetDestinations()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
```

This works ok from the client via a `InvokeOperation<string>` call. However, when I turn the DomainService method into Ienumerable, as follows;

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetDestinations()
    {
        List<String> h = new List<string>();
        h.Add("HELLO");
        h.Add("WORLD");

        return h;
    }
```

And then obviously use an `InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<string>>` call I get a compiler error:

Type 'String' is not a valid entity type.  Entity types cannot be a primitive type or a simple type like string or Guid.

Huh? This doesn't make sense given that I can return a single string. How do I return a list of strings from my DomainService?

Comment: Interesting at first I didn't have trouble with InvokeOperation<IEnumerable<string>> I used opresult.Value but then I started getting this error createriaclientfilestask failed ! .Even I tried @Alessandro's offer it seems same.

Comment: Ohh I realized that the error I got  was "createriaclientfilestask fail" depending Out Of Memory (Its 8GB but 3GB is free). Then I could built it after make my memory free.I did as you did web side returns IEnumerable<string> and on the Bus side I use it as invokop.Value.toList<string>(). We use SL4 and Ria Services V1 SP 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try returning an array of strings and marking the method as an InvokeOperation.

```
[Invoke]
public string[] GetDestinations()
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By convention the method that returns IEnumerable counted as Query method. Query method can return only collection of entities. Add Invoke attribute to your method.

Comment: But I succeeded returning IEnumerable<string> in RiaServices V1 SP2. If a method returns IEnumerable<Entity> its a Query method ok, otherwise we mustn't have trouble with IEnumerable<primitive types+DataContracts>. (As we know also by using DataContract,DataMemberAttribute's supports other web object's serializations.)